# How do i resolved this error <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

```
todoList() {
return this.state.todos.map(function(element,i){
    return <div todo={element} key = {i}>;
    <tr>
    <td>{element.todo_description}</td>
    <td>{element.todo_responsible}</td>
    <td>{element.todo_priority}</td>
    <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/"+element._id}>Edit</Link>
    </td>
</tr>
</div>

})
}

render(){
    return(
       <div> 
          <h2>To Do List</h2>
          <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Description</th>
                      <th>Responsible</th>
                      <th>Priority</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {this.todoList()}
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

    )
}
}

export default toDosList;
```

Comment: Don't put a TR inside a DIV.

Comment: Just take the div out entirely. Put the attributes on the tr.

Answer (score -1):

tr tag is a child of table tag, so you should add a table tag after the div, like this:

```
<div todo={element} key = {i}>;
<table>
<tr>
<td>{element.todo_description}</td>
<td>{element.todo_responsible}</td>
<td>{element.todo_priority}</td>
<td>
    <Link to={"/edit/"+element._id}>Edit</Link>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: got this error "<tr> cannot appear as a child of <table>."

Comment: That just moves the problem. Look where the return value of `todoList` goes. Now you're trying to put a `<div>` as a child element of `<tbody>`.